# Не работают сложные строки jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.gallery .entry').click(function(){
var counter = $(this).index().toString();
$(`.clicked-container .clicked-entry:nth- child(${counter})`).css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: как минимум лишний пробел  тут: `nth- child`

Comment: Все равно...Не работает):

Comment: чем докажешь?:) Почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: Извини, работает.Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Все таки там была небольшая оплошность.Из-за того что индексирование начинаеться с нуля, jQuery не находил видимый контейнер соответствующий первому елементу.
Тоесть:
count = 0;
И тогда елемент просто не находился.
Для решение всего лишь нужно:
${counter+1}

Comment: в текущем виде когда в counter у тебя строка `+1` даст неверный результат. Нужно как минимум убрать `.toString()`, который тут вообще не нужен